# Executing a java file in PHP

Tags: java, php, amazon-web-services

Hi I have a Java file that I want to execute when on a PHP page. I have a PHP file with the following content:

```
<?php 
exec('java sendMail');
?>
```

The PHP file is being run on AWS's Elastic Beanstalk, and when I run the Java file in eclipse, it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Its likely have issues with your paths. Depending on the context you are executing the code in, you may need provide the full path in the exec line.

Comment: When using Elastic Beanstalk, you upload a ZIP file with the contents. I currently have the java file and php file in the initial directory, so I don't think that's it. Thanks though.

Comment: what was the error? if you know linux then check if java is installed and executables for all users (via `which java`). There are two paths here: the path to java executables and the path to the java file